# Nesting with Images

Tags: image, nested, switch-statement

I am new to Java and am having trouble with this program I want to make. Basically I need a switch statement while nesting 2 levels of If, Else if statements and the Final product that the program should spit out is a image with text. Here is a block of the code.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
 g.drawImage(img,0,0,this);}

public void init(){
    currentTime= Calendar.getInstance();
    month= currentTime.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
    System.out.printf("%d",month); //checked that it worked
    GetTemp();
    parsetemps();
    weather();



    switch (month) {

        case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: //Winter

            break;
        case 6: case 7: case 5:case 8:  //Summer
            if (t1>=60&&t1<=80) {
                if (weather1.equalsIgnoreCase("Windy"))
                    img=getImage(getCodeBase(),"hottub.jpg");



                    else if (weather1.equalsIgnoreCase("Not Windy"))
                    img=getImage(getCodeBase(),"parasail.jpg");}

            else if (t1>=81&&t1<=100){
                    if (weather2.equalsIgnoreCase("sunny"))
                        img=getImage(getCodeBase(), "parasail.jpg");
                    else if(weather2.equalsIgnoreCase("not sunny"))
                        img=getImage(getCodeBase(), "parasail.jpg");}
            break;
```